# Using NSMutableParagraphStyle cause issue with emojis

Tags: ios, swift, string

In my app I want to change the line height, I am using this string extension :

```
extension String {
    func addLineHeightWith(alignement: NSTextAlignment) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = 5
        style.minimumLineHeight = 5
        style.alignment = alignement
        attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count))
        return attrString
    }
}
```

I am trying to apply it in a UILabel:

```
let str = "Hi%5E%5E%F0%9F%98%AC%F0%9F%98%AC%F0%9F%98%AC%F0%9F%98%AC%F0%9F%98%AC%F0%9F%98%AC%F0%9F%98%AC"

if let decoded = str.removingPercentEncoding {
     print(decoded)
     label.attributedText = decoded.addLineHeightWith(alignement: .center)
}
```

Here is the result in console:

[image]

And the result on screen:

[image]

Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count)`.

`self.count` is the proper number of characters in the Swift `String`. But the `NSAttributedString` is based on `NSString` and its use of UTF-16 encoded characters. You end up applying the style to only about half of the actual string. In fact, it splits one of the characters in half.

The easy fix is to get the length of the string as an `NSString`.

Replace:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count)
```

with:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: (self as NSString).length))
```

Comment: well that's perfect. Thank you and have a nice day