# Emojis in a UiTextView

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextview

I am adding tagging into my application.  The text of a tag will look like "{{@23235}}" when it is sent to the server, which is working correctly.  However, when actively tagging someone in a message, for certain emojis (not all), the following will occur:

Correctly adding their tag:

[image]

But when I space away (or type another "@" or any character really) it does the following:

[image]

The strange thing is, this only occurs on certain emoji types.

I tried fixing it by using the following function as an extension I use for String:

```
var decodeEmoji: String{
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {return self}
    let decodedStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)
    if let str = decodedStr{
        return str as String
    }
    return self
}
```

Which I use on the inserted tag value but it doesn't seem to help.

```
public func insertTag(_ tag: Taggable, atRange range: NSRange){
    let currentFullText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.attributedText)
    let tagText = tag.visual.decodeEmoji
    let tagRange = NSRange(location: range.location, length: tagText.count)
    
    self.tags = self.updateTags(self.tags, whenUpdatingText: currentFullText.string, inRange: range, withText: tagText)
    
    let attributes = self.tagAttributes + [NSAttributedStringKey.link: "\(tag.url)"]
    let tagStr = NSAttributedString(string: tagText, attributes: attributes)
    
    currentFullText.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: tagStr)
    
    self.tags.append(Tag(element: tag, range: tagRange))
    
    self.attributedText = currentFullText
    self.selectedRange = NSRange(location: tagRange.upperBound, length: 0)
}
```

Here is the Taggable protocol:

```
protocol Taggable {
    var value: String { get }
    var visual: String { get }
    var url: URL { get }
}
```

EDIT:

Found the answer here: [Using NSMutableParagraphStyle cause issue with emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266204/using-nsmutableparagraphstyle-cause-issue-with-emojis)
Thanks to @rmaddy

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266204/using-nsmutableparagraphstyle-cause-issue-with-emojis You have the same issue with calculating the range.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks!  I was searching stackoverflow for like an hour before I posted this and never saw that post!

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know if you want to post an answer or not?

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate. This allows people to find the answer from both questions.